How can I fix a base prompt in GitHub Copilot?
I'm using GitHub Copilot to assist with code generation in my project, and I'd like to set a base prompt or "fixed" context so that Copilot consistently aligns its suggestions with my project's specific requirements and style. Ideally, I want Copilot to reference this prompt to better understand my project as I type.
Does anyone know how to:
Define a base prompt or context within Copilot?
Ensure Copilot aligns with specific coding conventions or variable names?
Persist this base prompt across sessions or specific files?
I searched through GitHub Copilot's documentation and settings but couldn’t find an option to set a base prompt or context that would influence the suggestions.

Yes, you can set a base context, so called Instructions, either loading via file or text direct both are fine. These are many settings you can set:  Ctrl + , > settings > type "github copilot instruction".

The instruction is good for base context like coding convention (coding standard), language scope, pre-requisite API list,...
You may update to following version to have this feature
## Copilot

- Version: 1.245.0
- Build: prod
- Editor: vscode/1.95.1


